# Eclipse Luna for web app

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, eclipse-plugin

I started using eclipse recently, and I downloaded the Java EE version to create a webapp.

Now I have downloaded Version Luna (4.4), but i'm unable to create a web APP or create a Tomcat server with these versions...What am i doing wrong? Do I have to download some plugins?

Thank you in advance, and sorry if my question is too simplistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download this version" Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers"

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar

Tomcat:
window->preferences->server->runtime environment

To create a web APP:
file->new->other->web->Dynamic Web project

Answer (score 0):

you have to install a suitable plug in for developing web appplications in luna
either you can downloadan entirely new eclipse ide for java EE or you can install a WTP plugin in the existing luna version using the eclipse marketplace.